# Detect and stop malvertising using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to detect and stop malvertising javascript. I am able to detect iframe that is not related to our webpage (see code below). I am trying to develop a code to detect js added dynamically to our webpage.
I am able to get added js file to webpage dynamically and also remove the added file but unable to unload the functions and events of added js.

```
// array contains ids of iframe on web page
iframes_to_exclude = ['iframe_1', 'iframe_2', 'iframe_3'] 
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
// execute loop for iframe
$.each($('iframe'), (arr,x) => {
    let id = $(x).attr('id'); // get id of every iframe
    if (id && !id.match(/google_ads_iframe_/)) {
        // check iframe ids in array
        if(jQuery.inArray(id, iframes_to_exclude) == -1) {
            $(x).remove(); // remove iframe by id.
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Can any body help me to remove and unload js functions and events from webpage.

Comment: This may be a naive question, but why can't you just look for any `script` tags and remove them, much the same way you have removed iframes?

Comment: I am able to remove script tag, but the functions which are called not removed even after removing script tag.

Comment: why are you even loading the scripts that include the functions in the first place?

Comment: @JayLane- I am not loading script from my webpage, it's being loaded by some malvertisers during runtime.

Comment: Yes, that would be a problem! :) How about running a script of your own that sets all of the unwanted script's functions to null? That should de-reference them so they get garbage collected.